# I deployed my Angular app into Azure web app (Windows). After deploying, it is directly redirecting to home page

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I deployed my Angular app into Azure web app (Windows). After deploying, it is directly redirecting to home page, not asking for the credentials popup. I use an app registration and MSAL auth.

I want my app to ask login popup before homepage.

MSAL config:

```
auth: {
      clientId: 'xxxx-xxxxx-xxx-axxxxxx',
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx-xxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx',
      redirectUri: 'https://xxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/',
},
```

Comment: Hi Coder, is your auth configin the MSAL modulecorrectly set up?check once, 


postLogoutRedirectUri in addition to the redirectUri. The postLogoutRedirectUri is used to redirect the user after a logout.

Comment: Hi @Mohamed Azarudeen Z, i have already using postLogoutRedirectUri in logout method. But still not working.
 
      this.authService.logoutPopup({
        postLogoutRedirectUri: "/",
        mainWindowRedirectUri: "/"
      });

Comment: Can you please share the code which you have configured for Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure Angular application prompts to sign in before redirecting to the home page, try adding the `navigateToLoginRequestUrl` property in the MSAL Configuration.
This property will ensure that the user is redirected to the login page before taking to the home page.

Add  `navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true` in `auth-config.ts` of your Angular Project.

**Code Snippet:**

```js
import { LogLevel, Configuration, BrowserCacheLocation } from '@azure/msal-browser';

const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/") > -1;

export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
    auth: {
        clientId: 'Enter_the_CLIENT_Id_Here', 
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/Enter_the_Tenant_Info_Here', 
        redirectUri: '/', 
        postLogoutRedirectUri: '/', 
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true, 
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage, 
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE,
    },
    system: {
        loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback(logLevel: LogLevel, message: string) {
                console.log(message);
            },
            logLevel: LogLevel.Verbose,
            piiLoggingEnabled: false
        }
    }
}

export const silentRequest = {
    scopes: ["openid", "profile"],
    loginHint: "appname@azurewebsites.net"
};
```